# Moo handles => 'Role' not working

Tags: perl, moo

For the life of me I can't figure out why this is not working the way the documentation says it should. I have Googled the problem SO searched, looked at the source, etc. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong that I just can't see.

Here is the code:
    #!/usr/bin/env perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;

package Model;

use Moo::Role;

has ObjectID => (
    is => 'rw'
);

package Object;

use Moo; 
use namespace::clean;

has model => (
    is => 'rw',
    handles => 'Model'
);

package main;

my $xo = Object->new;
$xo->ObjectID(12345);

exit;
```

attempt to run

```
perl -MCarp::Always t/moohandles.t
```

and get this

```
Attempted to access 'model' but it is not set at (eval 26) line 20.
    Object::_assert_model('Object=HASH(0x1dfd118)') called at (eval 25) line 17
    Object::ObjectID('Object=HASH(0x1dfd118)', 12345) called at t/moohandles.t line 27
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegation essentially expands the `$xo->ObjectID` method call to `$xo->model->ObjectID`. But `$xo->model` is currently unset. You probably want to default it to an object that consumes the `Model` role.

Something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

{
  package Model;
  use Moo::Role;
  has ObjectID => (
    is => 'rw',
  );
}

{
  package ModelClass;
  use Moo;
  with 'Model';
}

{
  package Object;
  use Moo;
  has model => (
    is => 'rw',
    handles => 'Model',
    builder => sub { ModelClass->new },
  );
}

my $xo = Object->new;
$xo->ObjectID(12345);
print $xo->ObjectID, "\n";
```